# why C++0x standard committee rejected boost::shared_mutex?

Tags: multithreading, boost, c++11

do you have any info about the subject? any problem with boost::shared_mutex in particular and with reader-writer mutexes at all?

reader-writer mutex can be misused, e.g. frequent writer locks reduces performance, even in comparison with simple mutex. but there're a lot of cases when many readers often require a shared resource that can be modified by writer really infrequently.

Comment: It is accepted in C++14. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14

Comment: The link in the comment above should be http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex (`std::shared_mutex` is a simpler type, which is not part of C++14 but will be in C++17).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Anthony Williams is an influential member of the C++ standards committee.  He co-authored many of the proposals that led to the inclusion of the thread library in the C++11 Standard.  You can read his objections in [this commentary](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/211180).  Nevertheless, it did make it into C++17.

Comment: N.B. the equivalent of `boost::shared_mutex` made it into C++14, but renamed to `shared_timed_mutex`. C++17 will also add `shared_mutex` which is the same but without the timed waiting functions (analogous to `mutex`/`timed_mutex` and `recursive_mutex`/`recursive_timed_mutex`).

Answer (score 10):

As told in the [mail](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/211180) referenced by Hans, the problem with `shared_mutex` is its high overhead. Therefore `shared_mutex` gives only a benefit when resources are held for a long time and only few threads are competing for the resources, which is very rare.

I found another [detailed article](http://joeduffyblog.com/2009/02/11/readerwriter-locks-and-their-lack-of-applicability-to-finegrained-synchronization/) about the issue.