# Multiple threads get value of x variable but only one thread can change the value of x variable at a time

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java, I have a global variable x, what should I use to allows many threads get the value of x at a time but only one thread can change the value of x variable at a time?

Any example?
Thanks.

Comment: Just don't assign a value to `x` in the other threads...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow multiple concurrent reads, then you will want to use a [ReadWriteLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) (the [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) class implements that particular interface) to protect access.

Comment: simple `Lock` (or `ReentrantLock` if you don't think it should be avoided) should be used in most cases (I would say in all cases), even if you have many concurrent reads and rare writes from single thread. (More info here)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659295/why-c0x-standard-committee-rejected-boostshared-mutex]. it's a discussion why `shared_mutex` (analog of Java ReadWriteLock) was rejected by C++ standard committee. Considerations are language-agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should be able to use the classes in `java.util.concurrent.atomic`. These classes are containers for a single value that allow lock-free access. If you don't need a compare-and-swap operation you can use a volatile field as long as you're using at least java 1.5.

Comment: Depends on the type of variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ReadWriteLock to acheive this. Java java.util.concurrent.locks package provides different types of locks. You can use ReentrantReadWriteLock from this package. Code samples can be found in javadoc.

If the global variable is a basic data type, AtomicLong, AtomicInt etc in java.util.concurrent.atomic package should also be able to solve the usecase.